# Hinderance when attempting to add MySQL connector through Maven

Tags: java, maven-2

[image]When I use `mvn clean install` after adding the dependency in the 'pom.xml', I get the following output, instead of the expected `Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/6.0.5/mysql-connector-java-6.0.5.pom`-type of message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've only posted the end of the Maven output -- are you sure the new dependency wasn't downloaded before the tests were run?  It finishes with `BUILD SUCCESS`... how do you know something's not working?

What changes did you make to the `pom.xml` file?  If I could see those, I could offer some thoughts about whether they look correct or not.

In case there's any confusion on this point -- you indicate that you ran `mvn clean install`.  These are lifecycle goals of the project itself.  Some of what you posted makes me wonder if you really intended to run (thought you were running) the [`maven-install-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).  That would look more like `$mvn install:install ...`.

Comment: Greetings,

Thank you for the input. It seems that the dependency-download finished when I ran the command previously as mentioned by you. I was not able to see the dependency ".jar" in "Eclipse" even after pressing "Refresh" because I did not save the "pom.xml".